# Unable to locate the Xpath at run time even if it is verified

Tags: java, selenium, xpath

Hi I am trying to access a xapth which i have verified from developer tools and is correct. But at run time i am selenium is unable to locate it and getting element not visible exception.

My Xptah :  //div[contains(text(),'Current Status of Python')]

i could not find any iframe here but still at run time it fails to locate the element.

One thing i observed that in dev tool if i directly paste my xpath then there also it unable to locate it i have to click on the source of element( div tag) then my xpath works. Not sure what is this behavior.

[image]

Comment: That is not a normal text, that is a text node. You should use text to locate this particular element, it' better if you could use other web element to locate this web element.

Answer (score 0):

In XPath 1.0, the expression `//div[contains(text(),'Current Status of Python')]` selects any `div` whose **first** text node contains the relevant string. In your document, this string appears in the second text node of the `div`.

This is one of many examples where `text()` is being used incorrectly. It's almost invariably better to write `//div[contains(.,'Current Status of Python')]`.

(XPath 2.0 would give you an error for `contains(text(), '...')` if it finds an element with more than one text node.)